# oAuth2 token request failing using C# HttpClient but working in Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I am trying to request an oAuth token in C# doing exactly what Postman (where it works) is doing, but I keep getting Unauthorized. I can't figure out what Postman is doing differently.

**Here is my code below:**

```
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://myapi/OAuth/Token/")
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>[]
            {
                // new("client_id", _clientId),
                // new("client_secret", _clientSecret),
                // new("scope", "company-api"),
                new ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
                new("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            })
        };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_clientId}:{_clientSecret}")));

        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        await using var responseContentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var accessToken = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AccessToken>(
            responseContentStream, JsonSerializerOptions.Default);
```

**Here is what my settings look like in postman:**

[image]

Comment: Try changing your encoding to UTF8 in your Basic auth credentials generation.

Comment: So I think both are encoding to the same exact thing, but I switched to UTF8. I am just now noticing that my response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); is actually true. I don't think the problem is with the oAuth token request anymore.  I am now trying to figure out why responseContentStream is not properly mapping to my AccessToken class.  If I try to inspect responseContentStream I am not finding anything useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have a better time if you go with response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();

Comment: @akseli Still no luck mapping all properties empty. In the debugger I am looking to see the actual values returned by inspecting response.Content. Should this be possible? If so do you know what property to look for?

Comment: Check answer below. In any case, debugging async code is never fun, especially when dealing with streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your issue is that you're using the wrong Encoding when generating your Basic auth header content.

Switch from ASCII to UTF8:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{_clientId}:{_clientSecret}")));
```

Once you solve this issue, you might want to look into making your life easier to actually read the AccessToken from the response. I would recommend using the `ReadFromJsonAsync<T>` extension method for HttpContent:

```
var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AccessToken>();
```

You'll need the `System.Net.Http.Json` using statement to get access to the method.

If you still have issues deserializing the Json, the `ReadFromJsonAsync<T>` method takes `JsonSerializerOptions` as an optional parameter to help you adjust to your incoming data.