# Keycloak loginscreen not showing up like Postman authorization request

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, postman, keycloak

Topic may seem easy to you but, please read my question. I couldn't find what I need .

So I know how to send requests from postman. I know sending requests from  java , or .net APIs.

I am trying to learn using keycloak, learnt a lot. But all of the sources online says  click this collection name on postman
[image: authorizatioınat postman]

then  enter values in this section, and then get access token.[image]

I can successfully get token by doing this. But how can I apply postman's get authorization
function at an API.
For example I have a dotnet API or console project, how can I send auth request like  postman's this section does.

Please, beware its not a simple request being sent to an url.

If my question is unclear please comment.

--
Update. For those who are confused, I have come this far, this is sample rest request and it executes without error. But I need an redirectUri, I need to find out how to open an login window. What should I do.

Update 2: I created a simple razor webapp. Thens send request with it.
This request is able to get some HTML that can show login page.
[image]

It is not fully functional but , that is progress. If you have any ide how to make it work please comment

[image]

Comment: It is just a basic authentication request to the URL. Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75044125/oauth2-token-request-failing-using-c-sharp-httpclient-but-working-in-postman)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not

Answer (score 0):

The authorization "helpers" in Postman are just that.

They are meant to help with the authorization steps, in particular where there is user intervention that requires the browser that you can't replicate programmatically.

If you want to implement this in an application, then you should read the authorization flow documentation provided by the relevant OAuth 2.0 provider.

They will be nearly identical as OAuth 2.0 is an standard, but its worth looking at the ones for the particular OAuth provider you are using.  In this case Keycloak (although I couldn't quickly find the flow diagrams on the Key Cloak website).

Here are the Microsoft docs for the Authorization Code Flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

It includes a link to a Postman collection that shows the general flow without using the helpers which you might want to consider doing if you are trying to replicate the flow as the helpers aren't going to help in that regard.

https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/f77994d794bab767596d

From here, once you have the requests working, you can potentially use the code snippets feature in Postman to generate code for the relevant programming language.  (This example is using the password grant type specifically because of the issues with the user interaction).

[image]

Here is another link from Redhat which talks about mocking for testing.

https://www.redhat.com/architect/oauth-20-authentication-keycloak

When you submit your http request to the key cloak API, it should handle the opening of the login page and the redirects.

Your redirectUri should be defined when you register the client in Keycloak.

Comment: unfortunately there is no code button appearing when i click what I'm asking about . What you mentioned is valid for sample postman request. Thanks for typing so many things but it is not helpful

Comment: "unfortunately there is not code button appearing when I click what I'm asking about".  Sorry, but what does that mean?  The general point I'm trying to make is that you can't just copy the Postman authorize helper, you need to follow the OAuth 2.0 flow and that involves browser interaction (which means you need to deploy it and run it from  your web server and test it from there).

Answer (score -1):

Right Click on the Folder -- >

- Add Request in your PostMan
- Select Request Type  (POST, GET)
- Go to Authorization Tab
- Select Type to  "Bearer Token" and Past the token in Token text box.

[image]

if you are looking to get the code for it, postman generate the code snip, which you can git it from
[image]